# O que faz a expressão "for x in *;"?

Tags: bash

Vi essa expressão numa pergunta do SOEN, porém não entendi muito bem o que ela faz

```
for x in *;
do
    echo $x;
done
```

Isso imprimiu a lista de pastas do diretório que eu estava.

É para isso que serve essa expressão?

O que seria esse `*` asterisco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto, escrito da forma que está, faz a mesma coisa que o comando `ls`

O `*` está sendo usado como coringa.

Experimente deste modo:

`for x in *.zip;do echo $x; done;`

Você pode usar as mesmas regras que utiliza no `ls`, como por exemplo:

`for x in ./*/*.zip;do echo $x; done;`

ou

`for x in /var/log/*.log;do tail $x; done;`

Como exemplo prático, o código abaixo limpa o conteúdo dos logs no ambiente de desenvolvimento:

`for x in /var/log/*.log;do echo '' > $x; done;`

Answer (score 3):

O asterisco indica a leitura de tudo que há na pasta.

A variável `X` recebe os nomes dos arquivos individualmente, os quais são impressos pelo construtor `echo`.

Comment: Não sabia que o `*` lista as pastas também. Interessante!